# seach data & remove keywords from user input that not existing in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for MySQL query for searching data in one column.

for example :
store data is : `product by company 2016` 
user input is : `product company in 2016`

Our logic remove extra words in input and search with remaning keywords .

I am using `explode()` and `implode()` in query with and operator but its not fine.

```
$input_array=explode(' ',$input);
$query="SELECT *FROM products where name LIKE %";
$query.= implode('AND like %',$input_array)."%";
```

Comment: Per your update you need the column in before the `like` in the implode. You need to quote the strings and what is the attempted logic here, the wildcards I think are not how you intend. Take a look at https://eval.in/676920. Your column doesnt end with all those words ever though.

Comment: @chris85 you do not understand my question. if user enter keyword that is not a part of store data , just skip this keyword and search with user remaining input keywords

Comment: Oh, your updated comment. So is there a list of keywords in your database already?

Comment: @chris85  yes ,product name store as : "gucci women 90 by 2016"   if user enter "gucci women in 2016"  out put is empty
but i want to remove word that are not a part of store data.and search remaining  words

Comment: Define how you would know what word(s) to remove.

Comment: @chris85 just a query that iqnore words that is not a part of store data, and search with remaing words combination

Comment: Use mysql's built-in fulltext index and search function, or use other fulltext search technologies built on top of mysql, such as sphynx. Alternatively, you need to build your own fulltext index by extracting keywords from text and linking them with the original data.